# div is overflowing outside page

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` inside a `table`, which is required to overflow several `td`'s because of it's size.
This works fine on PC, but on mobile I have some problems with it overflowing outside of the page. Check the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Code:

```css
    body {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

.kalender {height: 60vh;}

table, td, th {
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

table {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

th {
    height: 6%;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

td {
    width: 14.28%;
    height: 15.6%;
    position: relative;
}

.outer {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 10px;
        }

    .details {
        display: none;
        background-color: gray;
        overflow: visible;
        border: 2px solid black;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 12px;
    } 

.kortNavn {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
}

.skoleFri {
    border-radius: 50%;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px; 
    background-color:red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.sfoFri {
    border-radius: 50%;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px; 
    background-color:blue;
    display: inline-block;
}

    div:hover > .details {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="kalender">
  <table *ngIf="datoer">
      <tr>
          <th>Man</th>
          <th>Tir</th>
          <th>Ons</th>
          <th>Tor</th>
          <th>Fre</th>
          <th>Lør</th>
          <th>Søn</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let cell of ukeEn()">
                {{cell.text}}
                <div class="outer" *ngIf="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngFor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn">
                        {{kort}}

                        <div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngIf="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true" ></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="details" *ngFor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        {{skole.skole}} <br>
                        {{skole.kommentar}} <br>
                        SFO: {{skole.sfodag}}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>            
      </tr>
  </table>
```

The overflowing `div` is the `details` class. This `div` MUST be inside the `td` because, as you can see, it's dependent on the `cell` from the `*ngFor` in the `td`, when it's calling `datoerContains(cell)` in `details`.

So I need to find a way to keep it stay inside the page. Ideas?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

your code for overflow  overflow: visible;
you Have To Set  overflow:hidden;

Comment: try to change the position

Comment: Change it to what?

Comment: use different position values  and test

Answer (score 0):

Instead of displaying the details relevant to the location on the table, you could display them somewhere constant - where you know there will not be any problems with display. Or at least on mobile!

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need couple of different outer classes with declaring right: 0 when it is near right side of screen (to open to the left) and bottom: 100% when it is near bottom line. Also, don't know if it is misstyped, but you are missing dot in front of outer. It would be good if you can show real code for further help

Comment: You need to give us or working example with full styling or URL to see, than we can tell you what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. I believe you can start from that

```css
body {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

.kalender {height: 60vh;}

table, td, th {
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

table {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

th {
    height: 6%;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

td {
    width: 14.28%;
    height: 15.6%;
    position: relative;
}

.outer {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 10px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    
}

table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
   .details {
    background-color: gray;
     display: none;
    
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
  
}
.rdet{right: 0; left: auto;position: absolute;}
.rbot{position: absolute; bottom: 0px; top: auto; }
.kortNavn {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
}

.skoleFri {
    border-radius: 50%;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px; 
    background-color:red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.sfoFri {
    border-radius: 50%;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px; 
    background-color:blue;
    display: inline-block;
}

    .outer:hover > .details {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="kalender">
  <table *ngif="datoer">
      <tbody><tr>
          <th>Man</th>
          <th>Tir</th>
          <th>Ons</th>
          <th>Tor</th>
          <th>Fre</th>
          <th>Lør</th>
          <th>Søn</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            




  
  
  
  
  
<td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>
<td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>
<td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>
<td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>
<td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td><td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td><td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="rout outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="rdet details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>


            
      </tr>
             <tr>
            




  
  
  
  
  
<td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>
<td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>
<td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>
<td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>
<td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td><td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td><td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="rdet details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>


            
      </tr>
             <tr>
            




  
  
  
  
  
<td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="rbot details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>
<td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="rbot details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>
               
<td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="rbot details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

  
                </div>
            </td>
<td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="rbot details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
  
            </td>
<td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="rbot details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>
  

                </div>
            </td><td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="rbot details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td><td *ngfor="let cell of ukeEn()">
7                <div class="outer" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn != null">

                    <div class="kortNavn" *ngfor="let kort of datoerContains(cell).kortSkolenavn"><div class="skoleFri"></div>
                        <div class="sfoFri" *ngif="datoerContains(cell).sfoFri == true"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="rdet rbot details" *ngfor="let skole of datoerContains(cell).fulltSkolenavn"> 
                        skole skole <br>
                        skole kommentar <br>
                        SFO: skole sfodag
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>


            
      </tr>
  </tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried to do something similar, but it seems to not working. On PC, it just expands the height if the page to fit it, which I don't want to happen. On mobile the problem is not solved at all... 
You example are similar as mine, but the "outer" class should be wrapped around the "details" class.
I have extended the code in the question for further advice.

Comment: Take a look at edited code. Only thing left is to maybe declare that it should open with bottom: 0; when there is no space at bottom

Comment: We're getting close, obviously. But I don't like the word-break; is it possible to let the div to the left overlap it's div(s) to the right, and the div to the right overlap it's div(s) to the right?
Also, when I use bottom:0, I get into problems where the red and blue dot's move to stay on top of the hidden div if the hidden div is very high.

Comment: Well it's easy to fix this if I could control the css of every individual single table cell, but as you see, the cells are made with a for loop, so all the cells are required to have the same class(es) and therefore the same css. So this will not work on my code.